# Editing the output in a pipeline

Tags: bash, dash-shell

I encountered a problem while writing my bash script

```
cutfiles=`find $DIR -type f |
   file -b $SAVEFILES |
   cut -c1-40 |
   sort -n | 
   uniq -c | 
   sort -nr | 
   head -10 | 
   while read -r n text; do 
      printf "  %s...%$((40-${#text}))s: " "$text"
      for ((i=0;i<$n;i++)); do 
         printf "%s" "#"
      done
      echo
   done`
```

Output looks like this:

```
  ASCII text...                           : #######
  empty...                                : ####
  Bourne-Again shell script, ASCII text...: ##
  PDF document, version 1.4...            : #
```

What i am trying to do is put the dots only when the file type is longer than 40 not always. Example:

```
  ASCII text                              : #######
  empty                                   : ####
  Bourne-Again shell script, ASCII text...: ##
  PDF document, version 1.4               : #
```

Is there a way to do it?

Comment: The `file` utility doesn't read filenames from the stdin. the `find ... | file` is pointless. It will always check the filenames stored in the `$SAVEFILES` variable...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `awk` solution of @PSkocik is very good.
Just for the record, you can do things (slower) without `awk`.

When you want to replace everything after the 37th pos when a string is longer than 40 pos, you can use

```
sed 's/\(.\{37\}\).\{3\}.\+/\1.../' <<< "$text"
```

Off-topic:
You can replace

```
  for ((i=0;i<$n;i++)); do 
     printf "%s" "#"
  done
  echo
```

with

```
   printf "%*.*s\n" $n $n '#' | tr ' '  '#'
```

EDIT:
Note that removing the `cut` is not possible with my solution, since the differences in strings can be after the 40th position and you want uniq lines in the output. When only the 38th pos is different you will get different output lines, so it would be better to replace the `cut` command with the `sed` command.

Answer (score 0):

Yo could use awk (should be faster and more portable than bash):

```
filter()
{
    awk -F:    '{
        if(length($1)>40) printf "%.37s...:%s\n",$1,$2; else printf "%-40s:%s\n", $1,$2; 
    }'
}
cat |  filter <<EOF
ASCII text                              : #######
empty                                   : ####
Bourne-Again shell script, ASCII text Lorem Ipsum: ##
PDF document, version 1.4               : #
EOF
```

Output:

```
ASCII text                              : #######
empty                                   : ####
Bourne-Again shell script, ASCII text...: ##
PDF document, version 1.4               : #
```

Comment: Why are you subbing out the end spaces, you can just check if `$1` is more than 40.

Comment: @123 But then the spaces would be included in the variable. I'm using `:` as a fields separator.

Comment: Yeah, but you are truncating it with `%.37` anyway so it doesn't matter.

Comment: @123 It matters for `if (length($1)>=40)`

Comment: That's why i said more than 40. Try `awk -F: '{if(length($1)>40)printf "%.37s...:%s\n",$1,$2; else print}'`

Comment: @123 Thanks. Fixed.